# meteor.js “tsega:bootstrap3-datetimepicker” record data using the SimpleSchema “type: Date”

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

Hi is it possible to save data in the database MongoDB using shcmatu set in SimpleSchema:

```
start: {
type: Date,
label: "Data rozpoczęcia wydarzenia",
optional: true
},
end: {
type: Date,
label: "Data zakończenia wydarzenia",
optional: true
},
```

generated by the package "tsega:bootstrap3-datetimepicker". Code in file js

```
Template.newWydarzenie.onRendered(function() {
    this.$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
      minDate: 'now'
    });
});
```

Now the data record as a "type String," the change "type" on the "Date" receives the following error on the server side:
"Match error: Data rozpoczęcia wydarzenia must be a Date"

Answer (score 0):

Use **[AutoForm 4.0](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform)** which has advanced support for input types, including the ability to easily add custom input types like the the b`ootstrap-datetimepicker` library. In you case, add the **[`aldeed:autoform-bs-datetimepicker`](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform-bs-datepicker)** package to your app.

In your template you can specify `"bootstrap-datepicker"` for the type attribute of any input. This can be done in a number of ways:

In the schema, which will then work with a `quickForm` or `afQuickFields`:

```
{
    start: {
        type: Date,
        autoform: {
            type: "bootstrap-datepicker"
        },
        label: "Data rozpoczęcia wydarzenia",
        optional: true
    },
    end: {
        type: Date,
        autoform: {
            type: "bootstrap-datepicker"
        },
        label: "Data zakończenia wydarzenia",
        optional: true
    }
}
```

Or on the afFieldInput component or any component that passes along attributes to afFieldInput:

```
{{> afQuickField name="start" type="bootstrap-datepicker"}}

{{> afFormGroup name="start" type="bootstrap-datepicker"}}

{{> afFieldInput name="start" type="bootstrap-datepicker"}}
```

For detailed instructions, refer to the **[`README.md`](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform-bs-datepicker/blob/master/README.md)** file and a demo **[here](http://autoform.meteor.com/types)**.

Comment: So I tried using the package: AutoForm 4.0 but I had problems with the update data after that package: "autoform" but are unable to see the data from the database responsible for the date. Therefore, trying to create a form manually